# Should ID's be encrypted fo AJAX calls?

Tags: security

I'm building an application that will do a lot through AJAX, and a lot of them will have to take in a userId, or documentid, photoid etc.

What is considered best practice with these IDs, should they be encrypted(before even being put into the html page?), or is just sending them as is OK?

Comment: client side security does not work

Comment: @GungFoo could the IDs not be sent to the client encrypted, and then be encrypted in the ajax call and be decrypted server side?

Comment: @OmarJackman I am using microsofts MVC4 platform with c# and Web Api

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your doing with the IDs. We are building an application that is stateless on the server and so we send IDs as part of the request in order retrieve the entity, apply the necessary business logic and persist it back. In this case we definitely need to encrypt the ID in order to guard against [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4).

There are other options too, for example you could apply authorization on the entity on the server before applying any changes on that entity. This of course assumes that you have authentication capabilities. In our case we don't authenticate therefore this kind of authorization would not work anyhow.

Just an update on this we don't ever need the ID unencrypted on the client though and therefore its the server that encrypts it and sends in the first response. Subsequent requests are made which include the encrypted IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to hide the ids of certain rows (from a database?) you can simply encrypt them asynchronically and set them as a cookie. That way you won't have to care about them when doing the ajax request since they will just be available anyways.

If you want to do some selections and send them as a result of a form submit, the same encryption method without cookies works.

but to be honest, i hardly see any reason to encrypt database ids.